# library that compute precision recall from fitted random forest in r

Tags: r, random-forest, precision-recall

Is there a library that compute precision and recall of a fitted model in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the caret package might help. 
https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html

Comment: prSummary(test_set, lev = levels(test_set$obs))